# How do I suppress middleware errors (Sessions)

Tags: node.js

I am using Node.JS with Express.  I have included the "express-session" package, and the sessionStore is a MySQL database.  Per the documentation, I am using this middleware function:

```
app.use(session({
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    secret: 'thistestsecret',
    store: sessionStore,
    cookie: { secure: false }
}));
```

Everything works fine but when the MySQL database is not available, the user sees a lot of detail in the browser:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
at Object._errnoException (util.js:1024:11)
at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1046:20)
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1182:14)
--------------------
at Protocol._enqueue (C:\Users\XXX\node_projects\web_Proj2\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)
```

Is there a way to trap the error or suppress the detail sent to the browser?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it shown in production mode or just in dev mode?

Comment: Thank you Anthony. I was in dev mode. Doh!!  Problem solved.